# How to remove working tree from a Git repository

Tags: git

I'd like to convert my Git repository to a bare one. I distinctly remember something like git remove-tree that did the job previously but I can't find it on 1.7. Could you help me out?

---

Thanks guys, that did it with the moving of repo to a different place and then setting the bare=true option.

I must say my memory has failed me this time. The trick with removing working copy that I did previously was with Bazaar :)

Anyways - thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cloning your git repository, as suggested in [Skydreamer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380741/how-to-remove-working-tree-from-a-git-repository/7380785#7380785), may be fine for what you want, but it would lose remote-tracking branches, settings in `.git/config`, etc.  An alternative is to just reuse the `.git` directory as a bare repository, e.g. by doing:

```
cd my-repo
mv .git ../my-repo.git
cd ../my-repo.git
git config core.bare true
```

... which will leave `my-repo` with just your working tree, and `my-repo.git` as a bare version of the same repository.

Answer (score 2):

`git clone --bare old_directory new_directory`