# How can I cleanup git working file set (like hg up -r null)?

Tags: git

How can I cleanup git working file set (like `hg up -r null`)?

So only `$proj/.git` hierarchy present and `git st` don't show `D` (deleted).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove working tree from a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380741/how-to-remove-working-tree-from-a-git-repository)

Comment: ... or http://stackoverflow.com/q/2199897/223092

Comment: @Mark Longair. Similar but not exactly same. **git config core.bare true** does not delete working tree...

Comment: What's mentioned in both of those answers is that you can just move your `.git` directory to somewhere else, set that config option, and it's a bare repository.  You can then just delete the working tree directory that used to also contain the `.git` directory.

Comment: I exactly that git can not perform such operation. It is possible update to **ZERO** rev? that is much exactly that **hg up -r null** do...

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Do you want to create a new *root* commit, with no files in it?  Or do you want to create a new commit on top of your current one, but where all the files in your repository are removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After clarifications in your comments, it seems that you want to create a new root commit in your repository.  There's a [description of how to do this](http://book.git-scm.com/5_creating_new_empty_branches.html) in the git community book.

First, make sure that the output of `git status` is clean, so that you don't lose any of your previous work unintentionally.  Then if you do the following:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/newbranch 
rm .git/index 
git clean -fdx 
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Initial empty commit'
```

Then you will be on a new branch called `newbranch`, with a single root commit with an empty tree.  If you then decide that you want this to be your new master branch, you can do:

```
git branch -m master oldmaster
git branch -m newbranch master
```

... which renames your old `master` branch to `oldmaster`, and then renames the new `newbranch` branch to `master`.

Comment: Thanks for spending time to answer my question!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to what @Mark Longair mentioned, using `git checkout --orphan`:

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch
git rm -rf .
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Initial empty commit'
```

Much more straightforward in my opinion