# Convert a Git working directory to a bare-like repository?

Tags: git, git-clean

Our development environment uses multiple repositories as part of an overall build system.  The build dynamically adapts depending on which repositories you have checked out: if you don't need to build a particular component, just don't clone it.

However, once you *have* cloned a component, removing it from the build is problematic:

- You can delete the files in the working directory, but `git status` will show uncommitted changes
- You can delete the repository, at the expense of re-cloning when you need it again
- You can move the repository, but your multi-repo tools might "helpfully" re-clone

Is there a better way to remove the working directory's files?  Something akin to `hg co null` or `p4 sync ...#none`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After finding [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673407/how-do-i-clear-my-local-working-directory-in-git) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380741/how-to-remove-working-tree-from-a-git-repository) that didn't quite do what I want, [this article](http://bitflop.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-and-empty-branch-in-git.html) provided the answer: create an empty branch.

```
git checkout --orphan empty
git rm -rf .
git commit --allow-empty -m "An empty working directory"
```

Of course, ensure you've committed any important files to your repo first.  I've called this branch `empty`, but you can give it any name via the `checkout` command.

Once set up, you can switch to any branch to get your files back:

```
git checkout master
```

When you need to "remove" the working directory, commit your changes, then run:

```
git checkout empty
```

This removes all tracked files.  If you also need to remove untracked files and directories, follow this up with:

```
git clean -fdx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--assume-unchanged` feature:

```
git ls-files big-unused-component | xargs git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

Then, you can remove your files:

```
rm -rf big-unused-component
```

The first command lists all the tracked files in the `big-unused-component` directory, and then `update-index --assume-unchanged` sets the "assume this file is unchanged" bit in the Git index. Then, when you remove that whole directory, Git doesn't consider that a change.

To undo the effect of the previous command, repeat it with `--no-assume-unchanged`. The `git ls-files -v` command can show you which files have been ignored in this way.

Comment: That's a much more difficult command to remember than `git checkout empty`.

Comment: @Syeberman: I'm afraid I'm failing to see how creating an empty branch solves your problem at all. Wouldn't creating a branch remove *all* the files from the repository?

Comment: Actually, that's *exactly* what I'm trying to do.  Mercurial has `hg co null` and Perforce `p4 sync ...#none`.  I needed a way to remove tracked files while still keeping all the history in the .git directory.

Answer (score 0):

`git clean` can be used with various arguments to remove items that aren't checked in and committed, and sounds like a much better option than anything you came up with above.  Creating a new branch seems completely  counter intuitive as does committing false changes that erase things just to be restored separately.

For many of my own CI build scripts I do use something like this to make sure the build area is 100% pristine to what git has for it: `git clean -f -x -d`

However upon further reading, the confusing nature of your problem becomes slightly more evident.  It sounds like you have multiple seperate repositories in a common folder and your 'build' process separately uses them all for various things.

I could come up with two obvious ways to address the problem:
1. Subtree merging : Create a repo/branch whose sole purpose is for you to subtree merge the desired versions of other repos in together so that you have a repeatable build
2. Use symlinks to the repos in your 'build' directory so that you can blow away symlinks to repo's that you don't want taking part in a given build without blowing away the repo's existence only to be recloned later.

Comment: That will remove untracked files and directories, yes.  What I need is a way to remove *tracked* files, but only temporarily.

Comment: Updated.  That aside removing tracked files means you are using git wrong. Perhaps instead of asking how to implement some odd scheme involving numerous bad practices, you could directly ask a question regarding the goal you are trying to reach

Comment: I should clarify my statement above; removing tracked files in itself is not wrong.  That's of course why git rm exists :-p Removing them  not for the purposes of actually removing them from GIT but just to 'build' is what I was trying to say was 'wrong'.

Comment: Right or wrong, it's the development environment I find myself in.