# Remove working files from git repository, to save space

Tags: git, file, diskspace

I have a number of GitHub projects on my disk, but many of them are not in active use.

I would like to remove the working files for the time being, because they are stored in the commit history anyway, so I can retrieve them at a later time.

The easiest way to remove the files is `rm -rf *` but it has a number of drawbacks:

- It doesn't remove dotfiles such as `.gitignore`
- If I come back later, `git status` complains about lots of removed files.  I have to work out whether I should commit these removals, or if I had just removed them to temporarily save space.

What is a quick and easy way to remove the working files? And is there a way to do it cleanly?

Answer (score 4):

Creating an empty branch seems to work quite nicely:

1. Check that all your files are safely committed into a branch (e.g. "master" or "develop" branch).
2. Create an empty branch.  I will call it "empty".

   ```
   git checkout --orphan empty
   ```
3. But that didn't remove the files.  Do that manually:

   ```
   git reset --hard
   ```
4. The branch doesn't really exist yet.  Make an initial commit to confirm it:

   ```
   git commit --allow-empty -m 'Empty commit'
   ```

Now all your files are gone, and you are on a branch that embodies that situation.

---

Good things about this process:

- It uses git's own mechanisms.  There is no confusing dirty status.
- It is clear what is going on when you see the branch name.
- You can easily switch back to master with `git checkout master`
- You can easily switch back to your empty branch again with `git checkout empty`

Disadvantages:

- The initial process requires 3 commands.
- If you are not familiar with branches, or seeing which branch you are on, when you return to the folder you might wonder where all your files have gone!

Comment: You can also [convert your repo to a bare repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380741/how-to-remove-working-tree-from-a-git-repository) but then it won't be so trivial to checkout the files and get working as you were before.

Comment: There are a number of [other tips to reduce disk space here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/make-git-consume-less-disk-space), including [creating a shallow clone with no history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/make-git-consume-less-disk-space#35356887).

Answer (score 1):

If you use git 2.5.1 or higher, you can use bare repositories, and use `git worktree add /some/checkout/path branch` if you want to inspect or use its content.

The worktree will work exactly as a standard git clone, expect that all modifications you run there (commits, new branches, tags, ...) are applied to the bare clone.